# How to setup FreeNAS as a Windows Cluster storage target?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, truenas, windows-cluster

I have a VMWare Workstation running 4 virtual machines.

1. Windows Server 2012 R2 **domain controller**.
2. Also WS2012 R2, "**WS1**", to be a part of a cluster.
3. "**WS2**", sysprepped from "WS1".
4. **FreeNAS** (also tried **NAS4Free**, which is nicer) with an **iSCSI target** running.

My goal is to create a cluster and play with SQL Server on it.

I've...

1. Added this FreeNAS drive to drives at "WS1" using **iSCSI initiator** tool.
2. Formatted it and assigned a drive letter, then put offline.
3. Then I also added the drive on "WS2". After having been put online there, it already gets a drive letter and shows itself as formatted.
4. Next I put it offline.

*So the drive is there on both machines and is offline*.

But then I try to create a cluster and no matter what I do, this drive doesn't show up in Storages. Sometimes I get the warning about drive being unavailable and a suggestion to run `Clear-ClusterDiskReservation`. Even if I do, the tests later just say `Test cancelled`.

Also, later the drive can't be used on **WS1** and **WS2**. It just shows up as RAW after being put online on any of the servers. This seems to be fixable only by restart of the FreeNAS server.

So, what do I do to make the whole thing work? I've tried these tutorials, but there everything unfortunately goes smoothly.

http://www.ekzorchik.ru/wordpress/2012/12/server2008-failover-cluster-iscsi-freenas/
http://www.sysprobs.com/setup-windows-2008-cluster-vmware-workstation

Answer (score 5):

I used FreeNAS for a few months a while ago and gave up on it from too many bugs, especially around SMB, obviously, that is native to Windows environments. In you FreeNAS case I would suggest you bring the FreeNAS drive online, add to FC as available storage and then add as CSV. That works for me.

Since your approach is to deploy a cluster and run SQL Server on it, it seems to me [StarWind Virtual SAN Free](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free) is a better choice here. StarWind does a presentation of local storage as iSCSI target to Failover Cluster. For my Hyper-V cluster, StarWind storage was added as CSV to store running VMs. So far, I have no issues with it, only pros (StarWind storage is beneficial for me due to built-in WB RAM caching functionality).

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the drive in service and then put it on a NTFS or FAT file system.

Comment: FAT? Unfortunately your advice is wrong. FAT isn't supported with CSVFSv1/v2. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612868(v=ws.11).aspx "In Windows Server 2012 R2, you cannot use a disk for a CSV that is formatted with FAT or FAT32."

Comment: Totally agree, FAT as a file system right now can be used in USB drives for the car players:)